# Odd document.location.href issue in IE with URL Fragment Issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url

We are using the jQuery Address plugin to sort filters in the url of a page. For example:

```
/Page.aspx#/?PageIndex=0&SortFieldName=Name&SortDirection=ASC
```

Now when you are on the page and changing the filter it updates the URL Fragment (part after #) using the jQuery Address functions. but on other pages we sometimes want to link directly to the URL above instead of just

```
/Page.aspx
```

It all browsers but IE this is fine. We have a small function which simply does this.

```
document.location.href = url;
```

Where its passed the full URL with URL Fragment. Oddly though IE9 seems to ignore the Fragment and ends up on just.

```
/Page.aspx
```

But it doesnt do this all the time. For example I have another page which If i click on before going to a page with a URL Fragment E.g. I go to Company.aspx before then going to the Page.aspx#/?PageIndex=0&SortFieldName=Name&SortDirection=ASC it works fine..

very strange behaviour indeed

Answer (score 1):

`document.location` is [supposed to be read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location).

If you want to change the URL then you should use `window.location`:

`window.location.href = url;`

Comment: I have tried to use both to no success (should have mentioned that in the initial post!)

Comment: Can you tell me what is returned by `window.location.hash`?